# Understanding PDF operators - for iOS app

Tags: ios, pdf

I am tasked to create a pdf reader app for our company. After a few research, I became confused with the different operators inside the PDF. Here are a few things that I would like to clarify:

- The `Tm` operator is used as the starting point of each line. (Is my understanding correct?)
- If the `Tm` operator is the starting point of every line, how can I parse the text shown *only* within the specified `Tm`? e.g.:

  ```
   BT
      0 0 1 rg
      /Ti 12 Tf
      1 0 0 1 100 100 Tm
      0 0 Td
      (The quick brown fox ) Tj 0 −13 Td
      (ate the lazy mouse.) Tj
   ET
   //I only want to get the Tj and TJ string being positioned by the Tm
  ```
- I understand that every 1000 units of a glyph's height and width is equivalent to 1 unit of text space. So if the glyph width is 2000 and it's height is 1060, does that mean that the "real" width and height of it is 2 and 1.06 respectively?

Now I know that some of these questions sound outright stupid, but I really don't have much time to research. So if anyone can help me understand this, it will be definitely appreciated.

**NOTE**: The pdf reader app must contain search and highlight function, text selection, notes, bookmark, etc. Practically all the basic stuff you can find in almost every reader available nowadays. I will probably use a third-party library for this to make my life easier, but my biggest problem will be the Text selection function. So I really need to understand this.

Comment: If your experience is anything like mine, a large part of your work will be to (re)educate your management and coworkers that PDF does not work the way they assume it does, and is 10X-100X more complicated than they think.  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to familiarize yourself with the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), the annex A contains a summary of all the operators with links to more detailed documentation about the parameters, so that may be a good starting point.

The `Tm` operator doesn't necessarily set the starting point of each line, it generally sets the text matrix, which is basically equivalent to a `CGAffineTransform` in terms of Quartz2D. To move to the next line, a document could also use the `Td`, `TD`, `"` or `T*` operators. PDF documents don't necessarily draw their text in the order that appears on screen, they may move around on the page freely and position the glyphs in any order they see fit. PDF doesn't really have the concept of a "line", you'll have to infer those from the position of the glyphs yourself (which can be tricky for things like subscript/superscript).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well the `Td`, `TD`, `"`, and `T*` operators are not present in most of pages of the pdf I am using. So will that be a problem? Speaking of glyphs, the bounding box gives me this data: `x:-678 y:-289 width:2000 height: 1010`. I don't understand why it gave me negative location. Also should I divide the w & h by 1000 and multiply it to the user scale to get the right measurement?

Comment: It's been a while since I've implemented text selection in PDF, so I don't remember all the details right now. If you only need to handle specific documents that you know beforehand, it'll be easier of course. The bounding boxes are relative to the baseline iirc, so a negative value would mean that the glyph has a descender (like "y", for example).

Comment: As for converting text coordinates to actual coordinates on the page, see Note 2 in the "Text Space Details" section of the spec (9.4.4). Basically, you'll have to multiply the text matrix with the CTM, which is why you need to implement a bunch of operators that don't directly affect text, but alter the CTM, such as `cm`, `q`, `Q`...

Comment: PDF spec link is broken.

Comment: @Vesanto [fixed link](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) - already submitted as an edit, hope it gets accepted soon

Comment: As I cannot edit (message: "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow.  Please try later."), here is a working link: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf for the PDF specification.

Answer (score 5):

Hrmm... you've been tasked with a very non-trivial job then. You should tell your them that the PDF-1.7 spec is a dense document of roughly 800 pages...

Yes, it's a very good idea to use a third-party library for this. It's impossible for a single person to implement a conforming PDF reader that can truthfully display all the graphic objects, fonts, colors, transparencies, vector graphics, images.... that may be embedded in a PDF-1.7 (ISO spec) file.

The first few things you need to be aware of:

- PDF builds on the same graphics model as PostScript did. (But PostScript is a Turing-complete programming language, while PDF has been -- on purpose! -- stripped of all programming language capabilities.)
- Like PostScript, the PDF graphic description "language" is using *stacks* and it uses the inverted "Polish notation" for expressions: operators come last, arguments for operators come first. To express *"1 + 2"* you'd write *"1 2 add"* in PostScript.
- PDF is hardly "line based". So regarding your questions about `Tm`: it's not the starting point of a new line, it's the end of the expression `1 0 0 1 100 100` saying: *"the previous 6 numbers represent the setting of a text line matrix, and it is for now set to the named values"*. `Tm` would rather be the ***end*** of a line, than the start of one!

Comment: The 3 weeks are actually for text selection only, but yeah, it's quite impossible for me. Thanks for clarifying the `Tm` by the way! About the 3rd-party library, I've been searching for one but it seems like no one was willing to share their code haha. I've seen `PDFKitten`, but it seems to me that it is made for searching & highlight only. It is very hard to modify it into implementing Text Selection. So if you know any 3rd-party library which could help me, please tell me so. It would mean a lot! :D

Comment: @Anna Fortuna: What is the reason your company wants to write its own PDF reader? Why can't it simply use one of the existing ones?!

Comment: @Anna Fortuna: Have you ever heard of `pdf.js`? This is a (new) PDF reader that's written in pure JavaScript+HTML5. It's got working text selection too. Will run in every browser. Developed by Mozilla people. Will be official part of the next Firefox release. For now, install it as an Add-on in Firefox or Chrome. Source code: http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/

Comment: For commercial purposes! :D Actually the e-book reader is just a part of a e-learning system we're developing. Since it will be an opportunity for additional revenue, our company decided to create our own pdf reader. I just tried this pdf.js and it looks good, but will it help me in my app? I mean will I be able to integrate it in my project?

Comment: @Anna Fortuna: I can't tell you that. I know too little about your project, its technology, its purpose, its scope....