# Understanding the Text-Positioning Operators in PDF

Tags: pdf, position

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding PDF operators - for iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258551/understanding-pdf-operators-for-ios-app)

I want to understand how does the `Td`, `TD`, and `T*` operators affect the `Tm`.

For example we have this info:

```
Tm: (20, 0, 0, 20, 100, 200)
Td: 4.1001, 0
TD: 2.8961, 0
T*: 1.2219, 0
```

Now how will these operators affect the `Tm`?

Should I multiply these values? Subtract, add? Please help me understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11258551/821436

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These operators affect the current point and as such only affect the Tx and Ty members of the Text Matrix. The PDF Reference manual has a reasonably clear definition on p406 (of the 1.7 reference).

For Td you take the current text line matrix, multiply with the implicit matrix with the Tx and Ty supplied to Td (ie the matrix is [1 0 0 1 Tx Ty]) and the result becomes both the new Text Matrix and the new Text Line Matrix.

TD is exactly the same except that it also sets the leading parameter in the text state to -Ty.

T* has the same effect as Td, but it uses the current text leading for Ty and has Tx = 0.

Transformation matrices are described in section 4.2.3 of the reference,

Comment: You explained it clearly. Thanks!

Comment: I have additional question though, The Tlm or Text Line Matrix, is it safe to say that it is the beginning of every line?